# Dart Angular2 - javascript method interop to modify view

Tags: angular, dart

In my angular2 component, I have a declared a javascript method where I change the value of a component variable :

```
   js.context["myMethod"] = (js.JsObject parameters) async {
       myVariable = true;
   }
```

However, when I call this method, my view doesn't reflect the value of `myVariable`.

Indeed, in my template the value : `{{myVariable}}` is always displayed as `false`.

The call to `myMethod` is made from my html file (I need to use a javascript library and I call `myMethod` in a callback function).

Is there a way to force the refresh of the view after my variable changed?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide more code and more information about what you try to accomplish. I don't understand the problem. Why do you use JS-interop?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Please add the code of your component. Why do you expect the view to update when you modify `myVariable`?

Comment: I expect the view to update because in my template I have conditions like `*ngIf="myVariable"`. Thanks for your time, I''ll try another way.

Comment: With this tiny fragments I'm not able to get an idea about what you try to accomplish. Maybe someone else ...

Comment: Where exactly do you call `myMethod`